Need help for centralizing navigation with flutter bloc
So I am currently working on a project that uses the BLoC architectural pattern and I am quite new to it.
I am looking for a way to handle my navigation in a centralized fashion. Navigation in my project currently works like this :
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<AppBloc, AppState>(
      listener: (context, state) async {
        if ((state.status == AppStatus.loggedIn ||
                state.status == AppStatus.firstUse) &&
            !_isInit) {
          await _initializeDependencies(context, state).then((value) {
            _isInit = true;
            _initialRedirect(state, context);
          });

          return;
        } else if (state.status == AppStatus.loading) {
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) => _initialRedirect(
              state, context,
              splashScreenLoadingText: (state as Loadingstate).loadingMessage));
        } else {
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero)
              .then((value) => _initialRedirect(state, context));
        }
      },
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}

For example I allow user to change the app language and it is managed through the AppBloc. As I find it smoother to display a 2s loading screen with a loading message I handle that directly in the AppBloc such as follow :
Future<void> _onUpdateAppLanguageEvent(
      UpdateAppLanguage event, Emitter<AppState> emit) async {
    try {
      AppState currentState = state;

      emit(Loadingstate(loadingMessage: "Setting new app language..."));

      User user = currentState.user!;

      Language newLanguage = await languageRepo.getOrCreate(
          {'code': event.languageCode, 'name': event.languageLabel});

      await Future.delayed(
          const Duration(seconds: 2)); // to properly display splash screen

      if (currentState is FirstUseState) {
        user = currentState.user!;
        user.preferences!.appLanguage = newLanguage;
        emit(FirstUseState(user: user));
      } else if (currentState is LoggedInState) {
        user = currentState.user!;
        user.preferences!.appLanguage = newLanguage;
        emit(LoggedInState(user: user));
      } else {
        throw const WrongAuthStateException(
            "In order to update user preferences AuthState.status must be FirstUse or LoggedIn");
      }
    } catch (error, stack) {
      AppLogger.logger.severe(
          "AppBloc._onUpdateUserPreferencesEvent raised an error : $error");
      AppLogger.logger.severe("$stack");
      rethrow;
    }
  }

With my top redirection function (in main.dart) in use here being :
// Initial page redirection based on auth state
void _initialRedirect(AppState state, BuildContext context,
    {String? splashScreenLoadingText}) {
  if (state.status == AppStatus.loggedIn) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
  } else if (state.status == AppStatus.loggedOut) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/login');
  } else if (state.status == AppStatus.firstUse) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/welcome');
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/splash',
        arguments: {'loadingText': splashScreenLoadingText});
  }
}

However I would like to be able to manage my navigation from a more central place and also be able to handle some more complex case such as pushing some splashScreen for a pametized amount of second before displaying the target screen. I first thought of a kind of NavigationBloc that would juste respond to NavigationEvent and emit NavigationState accordingly. I would not do navigation directly from this bloc as i've red from several places that it would be absolutely not following separation of concern. It would look like something like that :
class NavigateTo extends NavigationEvent {
    String targetRoute;
    bool showSplashScreen;
    String? splashScreenText;
    Duration? splashScreenDuration;


    NavigateTo({required this.targetRoute, this.showSplashScreen = false, this.splashScreenText, this.splashScreenDuration});
}

and the function within bloc responsible for handling those events would look like something like that :
  Future<void> _onNavigateTo(
      NavigateTo event, Emitter<NavigationState> emit) async {
    try {
      if (event.showSplashScreen) {
        emit(NavigationState(
            route: navigationConstants.splashScreenRoute,
            splashScreenText: event.splashScreenText));

        // wait for splah screen duration to complete
        await Future.delayed(event.splashScreenDuration == null
            ? navigationConstants.defaultSplashScreenDuration
            : event.splashScreenDuration!);

        emit(NavigationState(route: event.targetRoute));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      AppLogger.logger
          .severe("NavigationBloc._onNavigationEvent caught an exception : $e");
      // HANDLE ERROR HERE => PUSH ERROR SCREEN
    }
  }

But anyway this approach does not feel perfectly clean to me and I would also have to stack two BlocListener in my top widget tree in order to handle AppState changes and also NavigationState, it feels very hacky to me and open to issues in the future.
I also thought of adding some navigation data in my AppBloc in order to have only to liste to a single bloc but this would break the principle of separation of concern as well.
I found some posts such as Bloc, Flutter and Navigation but they are about very simple cases.
So, in your experience, what are some good way of centrally managing navigation in app using bloc pattern ? I've seen some people creating a NavigationService using a GlobalKey but I also have seen some other psots saying that this approach is not recommended
Thanks a lot for your answers !
As explained in the main part of my post I have tried to create a NavigationBloc but I am not very sure this is the best approach I could come up with here.
